# mips-linux-gun-as and mips-linux-gnu-ld compile mips failed

Tags: linux, gcc, mips

1. I use the mips-linux-gnu-as and mips-linux-gun-ld compile the mips assembly code! The code is here!

```
.data
    message: .asciiz "Hi, everybody.\nMy name is Alchemist.\n"
.text
    main:
        jal displayMessage

        addi $s0, $zero, 5

        li $v0, 1
        add $a0, $zero, $s0
        syscall

    # Tell the program that the program is done
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

    displayMessage:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, message
        syscall

        jr $ra
```

2.Then i compile the mips asseebe on ubuntu 18.04 TLS!This is my error:

```sh
mips-linux-gnu-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol __start; defaulting to 00000000004000f0
```

3.How can i due to this error?
Thanks!!

Comment: add `-e main` in your linking command to tell the linker to use `main` function as entry point.

Comment: I can't understand! I use this command ```shell mips-linux-gnu-ld -e main Func1.so -o Func
mips-linux-gnu-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol main; defaulting to 00000000004000f0```

Comment: Make the label visible to `ld` by using `.global`. That is, add `.global main` somewhere, e.g. on the line before `main:`.

Comment: sorry! I can't understand your! The code is this? ```mips .data
 message: .asciiz "Hi, everybody.\nMy name is Alchemist.\n"
.text
 .global main
 main:
  jal displayMessage
  
  addi $s0, $zero, 5
  
  li $v0, 1
  add $a0, $zero, $s0
  syscall
 
 # Tell the program that the program is done
 li $v0, 10
 syscall
  
 displayMessage:
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, message
  syscall
  
  jr $ra
```

Comment: Then i use the as & ld ! The result is also```shell  mips-linux-gnu-ld function.so -o function
mips-linux-gnu-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol __start; defaulting to 00000000004000f0```

Comment: Well, you removed the `-e main` option for some reason. So now `ld` defaults to looking for a `__start` label, which you don't have.

Comment: I compiled successfully! But I can't use the syscall to print the value! I use the qemu-mips ./function!

Comment: Those `syscall`s are for MARS or QTSPIM, not linux.  On linux, try calling printf or puts instead.